# Unable to send large transactions on ethereum private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, json-rpc, hd-wallets

I have a small contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract A10test{
 mapping(uint=>string) public data;
 uint public revisionNo=0;


 function setdata(string _data) public {
     data[revisionNo] = _data;
     revisionNo =revisionNo+1;
 }
}
```

I'm trying to save a file of 3MB in data using setdata.
I have edited the `go-ethereum/core/tx_pool.go ==> tx.Size() > 10000000*1024` to accommodate large transactions.

I'm able to do 2-3 transactions of 3MB, when I start a new chain and then I receive an error

> "error invalid json rpc response:"""

and my transactions do not reach geth.
Small transactions <100kb still works fine.

I'm using `Truffle`,`web3` and `truffle-hdwallet-provider` to send transactions

Plz help

**solution if some one is reading it now**
Changing geth version from 1.8.20 to 1.8.02 solves the problem

Comment: Why would you even save such ammounts of data on ethereum, the cost for it is insane. Consider using IPFS for big ammounts of data.

Comment: I have found that if I make a new contract, I can send 2 strings of 3MB and then start receiving the same error "error invalid json rpc response:"""

Comment: @Maxpeinas This is private chain so cost is not an issue and it is recquirment of my project.

Comment: @ahmed Ethereum blockchain was not designed for storing large amounts of data. For example web3js will require data to be supplied in hexa which is wasteful for such purpose.

Comment: @Ismael your are right but the waste of resource is currently not my concern. Can you please suggest any solution for my actual problem?